# Should an <article> image go inside article's <header>?

Tags: html, semantic-markup, article

Use case is a blog post:

- `<article>` element is used inside `<main>`, to encase an article on a post page.
- `<header>` is in use within `<article>`, containing `<h1>` title and meta including author, datestamp etc.

```
    <article class="card bg-white">
        <header>
            <div class="card-img-top p-0">
                <a href="image.jpg" title="Article title"><img width="1414" height="1011" src="image.jpg 1200w" sizes="(max-width: 1414px) 100vw, 1414px"></a>
            </div>
            <h1 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline">
                <a href="article-url" title="Article title" rel="bookmark">Article title</a>
            </h1>
            <div class="entry-meta">
                <span class="author vcard" itemprop="author" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Person"><span itemprop="name"><a href="/author/joe-bloggs" title="Posts by Joe Bloggs" rel="author">Joe Bloggs</a></span></span>
                <span class="meta-sep"> | </span>
                <time class="entry-date" datetime="2022-03-14T14:28:33+00:00" title="March 14, 2022, 2:28 pm" itemprop="datePublished">14 March 2022</time>
                <meta itemprop="dateModified" content="14 March 2022">
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="entry-content" itemprop="mainEntityOfPage">
            <meta itemprop="description" content="Excerpt for article">
            <p>Article text.</p>
            <p>Article text.</p>
            <p>Article text.</p>
        </div>
    </article>
```

Each post has a feature image. Does this image belong semantically to `<header>`, or does it not matter (ie. anywhere in `<article>`)?

I wish to present the image *above* the meta info, ie. the existing `<header>`. Visually, I guess it would sort of comprise the header area (ie. the stuff before the post body), but it would not necessarily communicate meta information about the post. If the lead image should not be part of `<header>`, this would mean it is also *above* `<header>`.

*(Despite presence of a `<header>` at top of page, multiple in-page `<header>`s are [permitted](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_header.asp) where semantically justified).*

However, found [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_header.asp) tends to pertain to the top-of-page header use of `<header>` alone:

> The `<header>` element represents a container for introductory content
> or a set of navigational links.
>
> A `<header>` element typically contains:
>
> - one or more heading elements (`<h1>` - `<h6>`)
> - logo or icon
> - authorship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've quoted, a header element "represents introductory content" of a sectioning element. If you consider an article's main image to be part of its introductory content, it would make sense to place it within the header element.

I've omitted schema structured data for readability.

```html
<article>
  <header>
    <img alt="A kitten." src="/images/kitten.jpg" width="100" height="100">
    <h1>The cutest kitten</h1>
    <ul aria-label="Article metadata.">
      <li>Author: <a href="/authors/katrina-whisker/" rel="author">Katrina Wisquer</a></li>
      <li>Published: <time datetime="2022-03-14T14:28:33+00:00">14 March 2022</time></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <p>There once was a cute kitten who...</p>
</article>
```

However, if you want to visually place an image before the header content, but still keep it after the header content in the document flow, you can use CSS to change the position it's rendered in. An easy way to do this would be with the [`order` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items#the_order_property_and_accessibility) and [CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) or [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout). This will change the visual presentation order, but keep the document flow the same. Assistive tech will present content in the order of the document flow.

This may be the best solution, because generally one expects to encounter the title of an article first, before anything else.

```css
article {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.article-image {
  order: 1;
}
.article-header {
  order: 2;
}
.article-body {
  order: 3;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <header class="article-header">
    <h1>The cutest kitten</h1>
    <ul aria-label="Article metadata.">
      <li>Author: <a href="/authors/katrina-whisker/" rel="author">Katrina Wisquer</a></li>
      <li>Published: <time datetime="2022-03-14T14:28:33+00:00">14 March 2022</time></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <img class="article-image" alt="Kittens." src="https://placekitten.com/200/100" width="200" height="100">
  <div class="article-body">
    <p>There once was a cute kitten who...</p>
  </div>
</article>
```

Additional notes:

- Don't forget an `alt` attribute on the image
- Marking up article metadata in an unordered list is more semantic than a `<div>` with spans.
- It seems you are both overusing and misusing the [`title` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title)

Comment: Thanks for this. <title> use wasn't flagged in validation. What do you think is the issue. Reading further, they're for tooltips rather than accessibility tech, so are you suggesting that means a) no need to use where there is a clear anchor text displayed and b) no need to use on <time> since that value is also displayed? Ie. Only use <title> to provide a tooltip where the value is not already displayed? Accessibility features more about aria-label?